# Filter an array by a second array when both arrays are defined by its own struct

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, swift5

I'm trying to filter theDataArray by theCaseDataArray where dataName in theDataArray matches the dataName in theCaseDataArray. As you can see by the code, each array is defined by its own struct. I've marked the line in the code where I need help. I've tried using a $0 and everything I can think of but no joy. I know there are a number of similar question on the forum but none see to contain an answer to this particular situation.

```
import UIKit
import SQLite

struct Data_On_Case
{
    var dataID: Int64
    var dataName: String
}

struct MyData
{
    let dataID: Int64
    var dataName: String
    var dataType: String?
    var dataDescription: String?
    var pricePaid: Double?
    var shipping: Double?
    var datePurchased: String?
    var dataDuration: String?
    var manufacturer: String?
    var venue: String?
    var performanceLevel: String?
    var dataNotes: String?
    var dataStyle: String?
}

class Test_VC: UIViewController
{
    private let crossRefTable = Table("CrossRefCase_Data")
    private let crossRefRCaseID = Expression<Int64>("CaseID_CaseXRef")
    private let crossRefDataID = Expression<Int64>("DataID_CaseXRef")

    private var theDataArray = [MyData]()
    private let theDataTable = Table("My_Data")
    private let dataID = Expression<Int64>("DataID")
    private let data_Name = Expression<String>("Data_Name")

    private var searchBarShowing: Bool = false
    private var isSearching: Bool = false
    private var searchingArray = [MyData]()
    private var theCurrentArray = [MyData]()

    private var theCaseDataArray = [Data_On_Case]()

    @IBOutlet weak var theSearchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}

extension Test_VC: UISearchBarDelegate
{
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int)
    {
        switch selectedScope
        {
        case 0:
            searchingArray = theDataArray
            isSearching.toggle()

        case 1:

           // Cannot convert value of type '((Data_On_Case) throws -> Bool) throws -> Bool' to expected argument type '(MyData) throws -> Bool'
            // The line below is where I'm stuck. The error is shown above.
            searchingArray = theDataArray.filter(theCaseDataArray.contains(where:  ))

            isSearching = true

            self.theSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            theSearchBar.showsScopeBar = true

        default:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` as below,

```
searchingArray = theDataArray.filter { data in
    return self.theCaseDataArray.contains(where: { $0.dataName == data.dataName })
}
```